# Can't connect RPI to internet via windows internet sharing ethernet cable

Tags: pi-4

I've set up a headless RPI connected to my Windows PC via ethernet cable and enabled internet sharing on my WIFI card to the connected ethernet cable but I can't connect to the internet on the RPI. pings are unsuccessful with hosts being unreachable. ifconfig outputs the following

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.39.174  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::c427:15eb:cdca:c582  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:57:b0:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 163  bytes 16867 (16.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 283  bytes 26677 (26.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have **NOT** "enabled internet sharing" on your Windows PC - not a Pi problem. If "a headless RPI" it unclear how you did this.